# Yii2 basic application page - load testing with apache jmeter freezes server

Tags: windows, apache, performance, yii2, jmeter

I had configured yii2 basic application template in windows server (Dual core processor, 8 GB RAM) No extra code written other than just installing it.When testing with apache jmeter with 100 concurrent users in 10 min CPU usage get hit 99% and the server freezes.Normal static PHP page would work without any issues under the same test, if placed outside the framework.It take around 2-3 percent of CPU utilisation.

Comment: Yii2 is a full MVC framework, much more work for the CPU than a static PHP page. What did you expect?

Comment: Sure, it has much more work comparing a static page but why the server goes unresponsive on 100 concurrent requests for a page even with out a database connection. I'm looking for optimisation techniques in Yii2.

Comment: you should add this issue on github yii2 repo where it would be addressed properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're allowing to run 100 concurrent PHP processes on 2-core CPU, this is more like issue with your server configuration - each process gets less that 1% of your CPU, which makes everything really slow. You should limit number of PHP processes (in php-fpm config for example) and queue them at webserver level - it is better to process 20 concurrent request at the same time and do it fast, than process 100 and do it slow.

You should start from [guide tutorial about Yii optimization](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-performance-tuning).

- Definitely disable debug mode.
- Use more efficient backend for cache (like APCu or redis/memcache) and session.
- Disable Yii autoloader and use optimized autoloader from composer: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-autoloading#using-other-autoloaders

You may also look at application prepared for [basic benchmark](https://github.com/kenjis/php-framework-benchmark/tree/master/yii-2.0) and compare configs.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions,i tried all the above said and confirmed it is server side issue,windows-apache server performance tuning was tedious,so changed server to linux-ngnix and got it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As per Patrick comment, you're comparing a simple PHP page with a more complex framework.

There are tons of possible reasons for your issues:

- misconfiguration of YII2
- Unrealistic JMeter test, you don't give any information on it
- Issue in YII2

Comment: Can you list out what would be misconfigurations after just setting up a yii2 basic template or what needs to be changed after installation.